# How to put a text next to an embedded picture in a tumblr text post

Tags: html, css

I have a picture embedded in a Tumblr text post, and I want to be able to add a text just on the right of it. My code is below:

```
    <div>
         <p style="float: left; clear: left">
               <img alt="image" height="73px" src="URL" width="73px" />
         </p> 
         <p>
               Text text text<br />
               <a href="URL">Text</a>
         </p>
    </div>
```

In this configuration the text is just under the picture, not on the right.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
  <figure style="float: left; clear: left"><img alt="image" height="73px" src="URL" width="73px" /></figure>
  <span>Text text text<br />
  <a href="URL">Text</a></span>
</div>
```

Note: Using the tag paragraph by default the display is set to block. Use instead span or set a rule to  paragraph display:inline-block

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vkh9S/)

Comment: Thanks but only the first line is on the right. The seconde one is still under the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply float also to text container `http://goo.gl/00dlLq`